# Beginning with OpenCV in Android

Tags: android, opencv

I want to create an application that detects walls from the image and paints it with color choosen by user . I looked it up and found out OpenCV is a way to go.

I downloaded the sdk and imported in AndroidStudio.

I am a complete beginner to OpenCV and i would appreciate if i could get just the hints where to start from .

I want to know what terms and methods to look forward(in the docs) in order to implement this particular task (detecting wall in image and fillcolor).

What would be the steps required to process and manipulate image for this operation ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with some tutorials. It is a best way to satrt with adn learn some basics and claasses and their usage.

Soem links are as follows-

[first-](http://opencv-srf.blogspot.jp/)

[Second](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html)